# Understanding When ListView Views actually get redrawn after calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview

From my understanding, there's no API for developers to determine when AdapterView's are getting redrawn.

We call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and then, at some point in the future, with no event for us to listen for, the `ListView` redraws it's views.

I say this because I've encountered a situation where I am updating images in a ListView when the scroll has stopped.

Every time I set a new list source - i.e. call `notifyDataSetChanged()` from my adapter, I then call my `updateImagesInView()` method - kind of like this:

```
//MyListView.java
public void setDataSource(SomeClass dataSource) {
   ((MyListAdapter)myListView.getAdapter()).setSomeDataSource(dataSource);
   updateImagesInView();
}

public void updateImagesInView() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= mListView.getLastVisiblePosition() - mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i++) {
            View listItemView = mListView.getChildAt(i);
            ...
         }
}

//MyListAdapater.java
public void setSomeDataSource(SomeClass dataSource) {
    mDataSource = dataSource;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The child views I get from the loop in the `updateImagesInView` method always belong to the previous dataSource.

I've hacked in a workaround, so I'm not looking for a "how to do this" answer, but more along the lines of - **is there anyway to know when the views in a `ListView` have actually been updated after calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`?** (or am I just doing something crazy wrong because the views should effectively be updated immediately after calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`?)

Comment: i am not sure,but if you create your custom list,when call notifyDatasetChanged(),onLayout call so maybe you can use this

Comment: Why not just treat the images as another element of your data source? I promise, you will regret trying to manually edit the children of a ListView from the outside in. :)

Comment: Both comments are interesting - how do you mean @SamDozor? I don't understand, I load the images after the scroll has stopped because 1) I don't want to waste the user's bandwidth downloading images they don't need to see and 2) it makes the listview scroll janky if I don't do it this way (downloading and drawing as I go). How can I treat them as another element of my datasource?

Comment: tried Adapter.registerDataSetObserver?

Comment: First - ListView is a nightmare of bad optimizations. Trying to guess which rows are visible, which are being reused, and when it all happens, is nearly guaranteed to cause bugs/issues.  Now regarding #1 - ListView will only call getView when it needs to display that row, so it will not waste bandwidth. #2/2.5 - Make the image URLs a part of your dataset. Then you can either roll your own (LruCache+WeakReference queue+scroll observer) to load the images on scroll stopped, or use a library like Android-Universal-Image-Loader which has this scroll functionality built in. Picasso might as well.

Comment: @SamDozor - it will waste bandwidth if the user scroll past rows they will never stop at (and hence download images they never have any intention of seeing). I also don't want to try and draw a Bitmap in three or four rows as they are scrolling out of view (especially where I am doing a slight fade animation) as that's a performance killer in listview.

Comment: I hear you - which is why you should not load the images until the user has stopped scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can add a listener to your`ListView`'s layout like:

```
mListView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        mListView.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
        Log.e(TAG, "updated");
    }
});

mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Otherwise you should listen on your adapter, as when `notifyDataSetChanged` is called, your adapter gets calls to `getView()` to update all the views that are currently visible.

Comment: Your first idea is promising. As for your second comment - the adapater also calls `getView()` whenever the list is scrolled. I'm not sure how to distinguish between a call to `getView()` when the list has been scrolled vs when it's called because the data source has changed.

Comment: @Adam I bet you could play with `getFirstVisiblePosition()` and `getLastVisiblePosition()` to determine if the list is being scrolled or just updated.

Comment: Your `onLayoutChangeListener` idea did the trick. I added it right before the `notifyDataSetChanged`, and removed it as soon as it was called. For the record, I still hate the way android does this, but your solution is a definitely acceptable workaround. Thanks!

Comment: @Adam What happens to the imageviews that aren't visible, you never set them? For that matter, when I scroll at all, how do you know to re-assign the ImageViews for each row to the correct image? The only way I see this working is if you're using the same image for each row, and even then if you fling fast enough, device specific, ListView may generate more rows to keep up, rather than reusing previous ones.

Comment: Each `View` in my adapter is backed by a model (obviously) and the view is a listener for that model. When I scroll through the list, I get the model item and see if it has an image that has already been downloaded - if it does, then just set the `ImageView`'s src in the `AdapterView` to that drawable. If it doesn't, then set a "default" drawable. When the list stops scrolling, I request that all my models update their images and when the models have finished downloading their images they call a method on their listeners with the drawable. Hope that makes sense. It sure works well.

Comment: Even if ListView does generate more rows, that's fine, because, again, the images are only ever downloaded for the rows that are visible after the scrolling has stopped.